# Check users currently logged in on a remote system with Nagios

Tags: nagios, snmp

In Nagios there exists a check_users function to check the number of users logged into the local system, but how do I do the same for a remote system? I have failed in trying to find the appropriate plugin.

Answer (score 2):

you can install [nrpe](http://www.crucialwebhost.com/blog/nagios-howto-using-nrpe-to-monitor-remote-services/) on remote computer that you want to monitor and invoke the plugin there.

or - if you want to hack a bit - you can write your own script and use ssh + key pair and execute on remote machine command like who + parse output locally.

Answer (score 1):

If you have SNMP enabled which has been my preferred method of performing remote monitoring checks. You can setup a Nagios service check that polls the `HOST-RESOURCES-MIB::hrSystemNumUsers.0` (*.1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1.5.0*) OID to get the number of users. This will return the current user count at the time the OID is retrieved.

The biggest advantage I find in using SNMP over NRPE as otherwise suggested is that if you find a flaw in your plugin you need to push that change out to every host that has the plugin installed on. For this reason I find doing agent-less monitoring better than agent-based.

Answer (score -1):

we are using this in production, its brilliant

https://www.monitoringexchange.org/inventory/Check-Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/show_users

Answer (score -1):

NRPE-2.14 ;)

install the plugins and NRPE on the remote server